# Firefox border of a selectbox is still inset while doctype is declared

Tags: html, css, firefox, border, doctype

I am making a form using text input fields and selectboxes. Each input is in another form td. I have a problem with the borders of the input fields. Unlike other browsers, Firefox default puts the border inset. By declaring the doctype this problem normally is solved (I use:
 `<!DOCTYPE html>`). Anyhow, it won't with selectboxes. Other browsers have no problem with it.

[image: firefox view]

Comment: Show us some css or it's hard to help.

Comment: Looks like a solid border to me, just with less padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<select>` has border-box sizing by default in all browsers. So if you're setting explicit sizes, you'll see the above behavior.  You can use `-moz-box-sizing: content-box; box-sizing: content-box` to override the default.